# How to restrict access pages to specific user?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm not a drupal developer but I need to do something.
I have two users with `Admin site` role. so the permissions of both should be the same but one of them can access to all pages even `admin settings` but the other does not have access to some pages and `admin settings`.
Is there some where in drupal to set permission of pages to specific user only?

Comment: you have installed access control module?

Comment: Access control will certainly allow you to set access based on user roles but if you want to set it for individual users, you will need to build a custom modules, allow to set permissions for individual users and store the same in db. When that user visits the page, you need to check his/her permissions from db and allow/deny access based on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the 'Admin site' role is actually an administrator role? It seems like one of your users is a real administrator while the other is not, since access restrictions are 'bypassed' for real administrators. You might want to check whether there is another real administrator role in /admin/people/permissions/roles (the default administrator role is 'administrator).

To access the pages, setting view permissions for the Admin site rol in the access control module should be sufficient.

In order to let the Admin site role see/edit admin settings, you should set the right permissions in People => Permissions => Administer xxx for the Admin site role.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new role and add this new role to the 2 user accounts. 
Set the page to be visible only to the new role you created.
You can also use actions, triggers and rules to do this.